# Unambiguous solution

Tags: linear-algebra

For $a \in \mathbb R$ we got matrix: 
$A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & 1 & 1 &0 \\ 
1 & a & 1 & 0\\ 
1 & 1 & a & 0\\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$. For which $a \in \mathbb R$ equation $A\overrightarrow{x} = \overrightarrow{b}$ got unambiguous solution ($\overrightarrow{x} \in \mathbb R^4$) for every vector $\overrightarrow{b} \in \mathbb R^4$?

Comment: There is exactly one solution if the determinant of the matrix is not $0$.  So find the determinant and then ask what $a$ would have to be in order that the determinant be nonzero.

Comment: Do you know how to compute a determinant?

Answer (score 1):

The determinant of $A$ is the determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix $B$ with $B_{ii}=a$ and $B_{ij}=1$. Such a matrix can be written as the sum of a $3\times 3$ identity matrix multiplied by $(a-1)$ and a rank-$1$ matrix made by $1$s only, whose eigenvalues are $3,0,0$. It follows that the eigenvalues of $B$ are $a+2,a-1,a-1$ and the matrix $A$ is invertible iff $a\neq -2$ and $a\neq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You need
$$\det(A) = 2-3a+a^3 \neq 0, \qquad a\in \mathbb{R}$$
So, solving it you have:
\begin{align}
a \neq
\begin{cases}
-2\\
1
\end{cases}
\end{align}